# website has recently shifted to cloud and it started throwing error "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

```
Partial Class Default3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("strCon").ToString & Server.MapPath("~/WriteReadData/betanewdb.mdb")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        Dim qry As String = "SELECT        [Year], Kinnow, Orange, Lemon, Mango, Litchi, Guava, Pear, Plum, Grape, Bair, Peach, Unit FROM            Agriculture_Area_Under_Fruits "
        Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(qry, con)
        Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
        adp.Fill(ds)
        grd.DataSource = ds
        grd.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

all   pages accessing .mdb files as database are throwing said error as my website is recently shifted to cloud it start giving errors on all pages. this error is from the server provider, as the code is working on my machine. but he is unable to resolve the same.

Comment: You need to set Enable32 bit applications on the IIS configuration panel (if you can)

Comment: However let me say one thing. Did you try to search about your error message? There are thousands of links that explain the problem. Probably you could solve your problems in a fastest way if you try a search before asking on SO.

Comment: You're right - so many questions on here are solved by a google search. I have resigned myself to posting results of google searches. If the OP is incapable of a google search, they are probably incapable of understanding a detailed answer

Comment: I have already tried all the sol. available on various searches such as:      1. Enable 32 bit application 2. installed  Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable  3. installed 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components , but it's still not working. that's why i have posted the issue here.

Comment: When you say cloud, what cloud? Azure? AWS? Do you have RDP access to the server?